# How to pass javascript array variable through jquery $.window url to codeigniter controller?

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter

I have a list of students with a corresponding check box each. The check box value contains students id that I need to pass to my controller function. I have a javascript code that detects the check box checked values and stored it to a javascript array variable. The javascript array variable will then be passed to the $.window url with a url address heading to my codeigniter controller function. This works fine when you choose the first student, it will show the student id via var_dump method, however, if the second or third and so on student is chosen, it says the uri you submitted has disallowed character. The same response when you checked all check boxes. The javascript array variable seems to passed only a single value to my codeigniter controller function taking just the first value of the student list. How I would be able to pass also the 2nd, 3rd and so on checked values or even to pass javascript array variable to codeigniter controller function through javascipt url with $.window. Images and codes are shown below. Thanks a lot.

Image choosing just the first student list
[image]

Controller output image after clicking send email button
[image]

Image choosing the second student
[image]

Controller output image after clicking send email button
[image]

Image choosing all student list
[image]

Controller output image after clicking send email button
[image]

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$("#send_email").click(function(){

var cboxes = document.getElementsByName('student_id[]');
var checked_val= [];
var unchecked_val=[];
var len = cboxes.length;
for (var i=0; i<len; i++) {

 (cboxes[i].checked) ? checked_val[i]=cboxes[i].value:unchecked_val[i]=cboxes[i].value;

 }


    $.window({
    title: "Coursebooking",
    url: "<?php echo base_url() ?>student_controller/pop_val/"+checked_val,
 });

 });

</script>
```

Controller:

```
function pop_val(){
 $stud_id = $this->uri->segment(3);
 var_dump($stud_id);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My revised javascript code. However, this changes only applies in getting the second value of the student list being checked, the same as getting the right value of the 3rd student list being checked. But checking all check boxes together returns a uri error saying "The URI you submitted has disallowed characters".

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$("#send_email").click(function(){

var cboxes = document.getElementsByName('student_id[]');
var checked_val= [];
var unchecked_val=[];
var array_val=new Array();
var len = cboxes.length;
for (var i=0; i<len; i++) {

    if(cboxes[i].checked){
       checked_val[i]=cboxes[i].value;
       array_val.push(checked_val[i]);
    }
}


    $.window({
    title: "Coursebooking",
    url: "<?php echo base_url() ?>ajax_student_controller/pop_val/" + array_val,
});

});
</script>
```

Image choosing the second student on the list

[image]

Controller output returns the right value

[image]

Image choosing the 3rd student on the list

[image]

Controller output returns the right value

[image]

Image choosing the all student on the list

[image]

Still Controller output returns the uri error

[image]

Comment: check the `$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_+-';` in application/config/config.php and add the required character

Comment: Thanks for this. I just need to add a comma character in the config file.

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
var array_val = $('input[name="student_id[]"]:checked').map(function(){
                           return this.value;
                      }).get();




 $.window({
     title: "Coursebooking",
     url: "<?php echo base_url() ?>ajax_student_controller/pop_val/" + array_val,
   ........
```

Comment: Just to use $.window not $.ajax because I will be using the pop up window.

Comment: Yes, the code above works when choosing individual value, applied when there is single check box being checked. Thanks for this because it solves the problem when choosing check box individually, however, the most crucial part is when I have to checked more than 1 check box. Then the code above just return uri error saying disallowed characters.

Comment: I found out that when there are more than one value in the array_val variable, the url looks like this: GET http://localhost/coursebooking/ajax_student_controller/pop_val/338,339 400 (Bad Request)  that cause a uri error. How would I solve this?

Comment: Ok. I got it. Just to add ',' in the config.php file $config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_+-';

Answer (score 1):

localhost/coursebooking/ajax_student_controller/pop_val/338,339     This kind of url causes the uri disallowed character error. A comma between the numbers 338 and 339. To solve this is just to add comma character in config.php file in $config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_+-'; and then use explode function in your controller function to separate the comma separated values. Here are the output:

Image of a var_dump output after checking 3 check boxes and adding comma character in the config.php file $config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_+-,';

[image]

Image of a var_dump output to separate comma separated values into array indexed values using explode function.

[image]

Controller Code:

```
function pop_val(){

 $stud_id = $this->uri->segment(3);
 $split_val = explode(',',$stud_id);
 var_dump($split_val);

}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 url: "<?php echo base_url() ?>student_controller/pop_val/"+checked_val,
```

Try:

```
url: "/student_controller/pop_val/" + checked_val,
```

Comment: Still the same thing happens.